# Spring boot repository not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my service class

```
package com.example.demo.service;
import com.example.demo.dto.Invoicedto;
import com.example.demo.model.Item;
import com.example.demo.repository.ItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class InvoiceService implements InvoiceServiceInterface {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    public void createInvoice(Invoicedto invoiceDto) {
        try {
            List<Item> itemList = this.itemRepository.findAll();
            for (Item item : itemList) {
                System.out.println(item.getId());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this is my repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;
import com.example.demo.model.Item;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository   extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    List<Item> findAll();

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE Item c WHERE c.id = ?1")
    void deleteById(long id); 
}
```

Though I added necessary annotations this always give

> Exception occurred Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.repository.ItemRepository.findAll()" because "this.itemRepository" is null

Why is this happening what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Spring Component Scan is not finding your repository bean due to your package structure.

Make sure the main class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is in this package: `package com.example.demo;`

Comment: yes it is located in there

Answer (score 0):

Here two things I can see in your code which are not required.

```
    1. List<Item> itemList = this.itemRepository.findAll();
```

to

```
    List<Item> itemList = itemRepository.findAll();
```

2. As you are extending `JpaRepository` no need to declare `findAll()` and `deleteById()` methods in repository interface. So please change as below and try once.

   ```
   public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

   }
   ```

References: [findAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--) [deleteById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#deleteById-ID-)

Comment: I tried but no luck. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually specify directory of your repositories with:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("some.root.package") //path to repository package
```

Comment: I use this repository in a controller too but it works fine. Anyway thanks !

Comment: @Nipunachandimal can you add another `@Autowire` bean to this service? Maybe the problem with service bean rather that with repository bean

Comment: To where should I add it?

Comment: @Nipunachandimal to `InvoiceService` . If newly added bean will be also `null` it could locate source of the problem, because right now it seems everything should work as intended

Answer (score 0):

```
1)List<Item> findAll();
you don't have to write this line inside the repository you will get this from JPA JpaRepository<ClassName,Long> Interface;.

2)List<Item> getAllItem();this line declare inside your service package 

3) List<Item> itemList = this.itemRepository.findAll();
            for (Item item : itemList) {
                System.out.println(item.getId());}
and here you don't have to user this before item itemRepository.findAll().
you can directly use  List<Item> itemList = itemRepository.findAll();
```